# Can't add node module to Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, module, typing

I'm completely new to Angular and TypeScript, and I am trying to import a node module ([ewelink-api](https://github.com/skydiver/ewelink-api/tree/master/docs)) to my Angular project (my very first one), but I can't figure out how to do it right.

I've already installed the package through npm, but calling

```
import * as eWeLink from 'ewelink-api'
```

or

```
let eWeLink = require('ewelink-api')
```

like some people suggest, doesn't work at all. When I try to `console.log()` the value of the `eWeLink` class (or creating a new instance of it), the compiler throws up a bunch of errors like these:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './data/devices-channel-length' in '/Users/user/Desktop/Project/node_modules/ewelink-api/lib'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/user/Desktop/Project/node_modules/ewelink-api/mixins/devices'
```

as if it couldn't locate some files and modules in `require()` calls inside the package. I found out that specifying the file extension in the first case solves the problem, but there are so many errors that would be impossible to 'fix' the entire *ewelink-api* package.

I thought the problem could be related to typing (had to do some research to understand how that works), and I found out that the package I'm trying to add already has a 'declaration' file ([index.d.ts](https://github.com/skydiver/ewelink-api/blob/master/index.d.ts)), but I can't figure out how to tell TypeScript to use that file (maybe with the `<reference>` directive), since it may not be recognising it and that might be the problem I'm facing.

I've also tried to do:

```
npm install --save @types/ewelink-api
```

and that didn't work, but I do have a `@types` directory inside `node_modules`, if that helps!

Comment: `npm install --save ewelink-api` , try out by removing @types .

Comment: The package seems to have some issues while installing , i couldn't complete the npm install

Comment: try older version `npm install --save ewelink-api@1.7.0`